# How to specify the number of elements in a List bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Is there anyway to shorten this to specify number of Xyz instances in the list? If I want a thousand of these, I don't want to put a thousand lines of <ref bean="Xyz" />

```
<bean id="Xyzs" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="Xyz" />
            <ref bean="Xyz" />
            <ref bean="Xyz" />
            <ref bean="Xyz" />
            <ref bean="Xyz" />
            <ref bean="Xyz" />
            <ref bean="Xyz" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I think putting a thousand of bean reference would be better and more declarative because it will highlight the problem with design if it's present.

Comment: If you could use programming configuration you would use Collections.nCopies(1000, xyz) to construct a `@bean` or set it as a SPEL expression in the property of the object that references Xyzs

Comment: Thank you. I understand I can do it in such way. But I'd like to know if there is an option to do it like what I am asking originally.